# plumberDeploy how to authenticate with SSH

Tags: r, ssh, deployment, digital-ocean, plumber

I am trying to deploy plumber API on DigitalOcean with `plumberDeploy` package. I created DigitalOcean account and already added public SSH key to it. I have private key on my machine.

Now I run:

```
id <- plumberDeploy::do_provision(example = FALSE,
                                  region = getOption("do_region", "sfo3"))
```

And get back:

```
THIS ACTION COSTS YOU MONEY!
Provisioning a new server for which you will get a bill from DigitalOcean.
Using default ssh keys: work_R_laptop
NB: This costs $0.00744 / hour until you droplet_delete() it
Waiting for create .........................
New server key: some_long_key
Error: Authentication with ssh server failed
```

But in DigitalOcean I can see that droplet is created.

Next I run:

```
plumberDeploy::do_deploy_api(id, "date", "digital_o_test/", 8000, docs = TRUE)
```

but get back:

```
Error in as.droplet(droplet) : object 'id' not found
```

Does this happen because SSH authentication error? I am trying to go through documentation, but I am still confused how to authenticate from R session. I can authenticate using Bash and OpenSSH.